# HTML tables display as variable px width in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

The HTML tables on my site look nice and the way I intend them to in Safari/ Firefox / Chrome, but look far wider than the set pixel size in IE. Any ideas?

The tables in IE: http://screencast.com/t/mm7G7yDI

The code: http://pastebin.com/g5YPaLc3

Answer (score 0):

@Alex: Change

```
border-width: .5px;
```

to

```
border-width: 1px;
```

and it should work the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying both `border="2"` and `border-width: .5px`. Remove `border="2"` and use `border-width: 1px; border-style: solid` and it should work consistently across all browsers.